# Content is not allowed in prolog : Sending SMS from Java Web App

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to send sms from my Java Web Application to a user's phone. I found a suitable piece of code to send the text message.  However, I encounter the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.omega.src.backing.SmsBacking.main(SmsBacking.java:52)
```

Although I have searched alot for this error, I wasn't successful to solve it.

Here is my backing bean:

```
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class SmsBacking {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        String username = "testuser ";
        String password = "testpass";
        String destination = "905XXXXXXXX";

        String requestString =
                "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-9' ?>" +
                "<message-context>" +
                "<username>" + username + "</username>" +
                "<password>" + password + "</password>" +
                "<outbox-name>TEST</outbox-name>" +
                "<firmnumber>1</firmnumber>" +
                "<message>" +
                "<start-date>" +
                "</start-date>" +
                "<expire-date></expire-date>" +
                "<gsmno>" + destination +"</gsmno>" +
                "<text>TEST Mesaj</text>" +
                "</message>" +
                "</message-context>"; 

        URL url = new URL("http://xmlsms.vodafone.com.tr/xmlsms/sms");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(requestString);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(conn.getInputStream());

        if (doc.getElementsByTagName("ErrorCode").item(0).getTextContent().equals("00"))
        {
            System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("Result").item(0).getTextContent());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("ErrorReason").item(0).getTextContent());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure the response is in xml form?  Have you tried getting the response and simply just printing it to the console.

Comment: When I printed conn.getInputStream().toString(), I got the following result: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@775c024c. I don't know what it means.

Comment: Try the following post to output the actual response.  From there things might get clearer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856195/how-to-read-an-http-input-stream

Comment: I tried one of the answer from you link. The result I got is 20. Is this something meaningful?

Comment: This means it is not XML so you should not use a DocumentBuilder for the response but treat it as normal text.

Comment: OK, I understood. I tried to send a test message to my phone; however, I couldn't get the test message. Do you think that I called the URL service successfully?

Comment: I have no idea of how this api works so I cannot help you with that.

Comment: Okay I see. Thank you very much. How can I vote for your answer?