# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am getting this error when querying a URL and get a json object. My json:

```
{"status":1,"username":"admin","nombre":"Username","email":"example@example.cl","codigo_usuario":"1","hash":"2938632bfdklsngh","imagen":"05c151584cc1e9aa2985b5bd0a3a4cd2.jpeg"}
```

Create the User class

```
public class User {

private int status;
private String username;
private String nombre;
private String email;
private String codigo_usuario;
private String hash;
private String imagen;


public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public String getHash() {
    return hash;
}
public void setHash(String hash) {
    this.hash = hash;
}
public String getImagen() {
    return imagen;
}
public void setImagen(String imagen) {
    this.imagen = imagen;
}
public String getCodigo_usuario() {
    return codigo_usuario;
}
public void setCodigo_usuario(String codigo_usuario) {
    this.codigo_usuario = codigo_usuario;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [status=" + status + ", username=" + username
            + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", email=" + email
            + ", codigo_usuario=" + codigo_usuario + ", hash=" + hash
            + ", imagen=" + imagen + "]";
}
}
```

And in my class, I make the request to the URL I have this code:

```
public static boolean authenticate(String username, String password){
    boolean error = false;
    User user = null;
    try {
        String request = Config.getText("URL_BASE")+Config.getText("URL_AUTHENTICATE")+username+"/"+password;
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(request).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new Exception("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        user = new Gson().fromJson(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()), User.class);
        System.out.println(user.toString());
        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return error;
}
```

And I get the exception. I saw other post with this same error and in most the error was the json format or class that did not have the same fields. Now, check well and everything should be OK. But for some reason I receive this error

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:741)
at controller.WService.authenticate(WService.java:29)
at view.Login._verificarLogin(Login.java:77)
at view.Login$2.actionPerformed(Login.java:44)
```

I'm new to Java and try to consume a web service for data and use. I think this is my best option but still do not understand the error.

Comment: can you print the service response before "fromJson" and check. Most likely client is not getting a json string.

Comment: and as I can print before? @Sanj

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856195/how-to-read-an-http-input-stream

Comment: Thanks @Sanj The error was mine, laid method = POST, when I was doing it for any reason !, GET was not getting an object json