# Android API Response handling

Tags: android

I want to handle the json response from my API in my Android app, but i can't find a lot of tutorials on how to do this, does anyone have some tips?

Android code:

```
                    URL url = new URL("http://thelinktomyapi.com");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    Log.i("JSON", jsonObj.toString());
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                    os.writeBytes(jsonObj.toString());

                    os.flush();
                    os.close();

                    Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                    Log.i("MSG", conn.getResponseMessage());

                    conn.disconnect();
```

Reponse part of my flask code(very simple)

```
respdata = {
        'imgurl2': 'google.nl'
    }
    resp = jsonify(respdata)
    resp.status_code = 200
    return resp
```

Comment: Those are not really working for me. I tried that

Comment: is this your valid URL : "http://thelinktomyapi.com"...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this I Think This Will Help**

```
                URL url = new URL("http://thelinktomyapi.com");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                Log.i("JSON", jsonObj.toString());
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                os.writeBytes(jsonObj.toString());

                os.flush();
                os.close();

                Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                Log.i("MSG", conn.getResponseMessage());


               DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
               StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
               String line = "";
               while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                     result.append(line);
               }



                conn.disconnect();
```

> Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9856272/5726600

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
String response = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
            String output;
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response = response + output;
            }
            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

You will get your response in **response** variable.