# My simple Android app doesn't send data to a socket

Tags: android, sockets, client-server

I have a simple Android app that is supposed to send some data to a server I have over socket with a given IP and port number.

On my `onCreate()` I connect to the server. This part works:

```
// connect to the server
clientThread = new ClientThread();
thread = new Thread(clientThread);
thread.start();
```

But the `sendMessage()` doesn't send any messages to the socket and I don't receive anything on my server. The function doesn't even show the log message so I don't know what is happening. What is the problem? How to fix it?

```
//TODO send data
                            clientThread.sendMessage(100);
```

Here is the socket thread class:

```
class myApp extends Activity{
//....
ClientThread clientThread;
Thread thread;
//....

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader input;

@Override
public void run() {
    InetAddress serverAddr = null;
    try {
        serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        Log.i("Hello: Connected","Hello: Connected");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void sendMessage(int data) {
    try {
        if (null != socket) {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(data);
            Log.i("Hello Message sent","Hello sent: "+data+" to: "+ SERVER_IP+":"+SERVERPORT);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
}
```

My server-side receive (Java server):

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Got a new user!");
    InputStream inp;

    try {
        /* Get Data From Client */
        inp = socket.getInputStream();
        int data= inp.read();
        System.out.println(address+" "+ data);

        if (data!=0) {
            scoreboard.b1.y+=1;
            if (scoreboard.b1.y==scoreboard.MaxValue) {
                System.out.println("HELLLOOOOOOO");
                scoreboard.updateValue();
            }
            scoreboard.repaint();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    }
    String line;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After `out.println(data);`, you should call `out.flush();`

And you read data the wrong way, if you want to read multiple times, there should be **buffer** and **while expression**, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9856272/5435312)

Comment: Don't think it, shout it!

Comment: It is weird. It only sends the message once. And the data is no `100`! The server receives `49`. I added the server code.

Comment: BTW, the `autoflush` was set to true so it was OK before. The problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: Yes.The while loop was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The sender option I used in my Android app (`PrintWriter`) was sending the wrong values. I changed it to `DataOutputStream` and it worked.

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
out.write(steps);
out.flush();
```

Also on the server, I almost forgot to have a `while(true)` loop to continuously receive the messages. Now everything works!