# Can't read a specific website page content

Tags: java, web-scraping, url, http-headers

I'm trying to write a bot that scrap my tiktok liked videos to repost it in a private twitter account. I'm trying the following code but it is not working on the link that I give (*the String s2 in the code*). But the following code is working with other website (*like the String s1 in the code*).

There is the code :

```
    String s1 = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856195/how-to-read-an-http-input-stream";
    String s2 = "https://m.tiktok.com/api/favorite/item_list/?aid=1988&app_language=fr&app_name=tiktok_web&battery_info=0.98&browser_language=fr-FR&browser_name=Mozilla&browser_online=true&browser_platform=Win32&browser_version=5.0%20%28Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64%29%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome%2F100.0.4896.75%20Safari%2F537.36&channel=tiktok_web&cookie_enabled=true&count=30&cursor=0&device_id=7063036855931487750&device_platform=web_pc&focus_state=true&from_page=user&history_len=1&is_fullscreen=false&is_page_visible=true&language=fr&os=windows&priority_region=&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tiktok.com%2Fforyou%3Fis_copy_url%3D1%26is_from_webapp%3Dv1&region=FR&root_referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tiktok.com%2Fforyou%3Fis_copy_url%3D1%26is_from_webapp%3Dv1&screen_height=1080&screen_width=1920&secUid=MS4wLjABAAAAVgmocO2icsccM7sWbsOrGVbtLWI95ckuqchBV6Xp4EB1TpNCQDRBdZ-sMnItg-ZK&tz_name=Europe%2FParis&verifyFp=verify_l1td19sm_5DseUBXr_J8Sh_4D3W_BkHD_l4QBi8kzyjXQ&webcast_language=fr&msToken=gcc7oLzFW46KbibjEdg_IpuKIflUWj0zNMrcdirXpbZskFJgO8eNab4IRArRABhorlOTWSZRGpxpsMhWyvxGJMTR7T1xzldFmKVCRyX5boPcmZh5hcw9XjbmDJSgbyppR371tq9G&X-Bogus=DFSzswVOf3bANtliSAdqKQYklTIX&_signature=_02B4Z6wo00001dSv8PgAAIDACtmoX.I3hl3Ur.RAABeBd6";
    
    URL url = new URL(s2);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    conn.connect();
    if(conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(url.openStream());
        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            String temp = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
```

Is someone able to explain me why it is not working please ?
Thanks so much to your answers ;)

(PS : the information returned by s2 are from the first account I found that configure to public her liked videos)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `not working?`. maybe you're just not getting 200 (not satisfying if condition). I tried the link and got 404 status code.

Comment: Hi thanks to tryning to help me ! I mean that the code is supposed to print the body of the webpage. It works with the s1 String (we tsee the html code). when I launch the s2 String in google chrome, it display a json that I want to use. In my code, it return a code "200" so it is supposed to work but the InputStream seems to be void because it never goes into the while condition ...

Comment: It is weird that you got a 404 status code ...